# Pagination on custom taxonomy

Tags: custom-taxonomy, pagination, templates

I'm having a tough time getting this to work. It's not the first time I run into problems with pagination, or I would say with WPs URL system.

Basically I have this URL:

```
http://example.com/location/dc
```

and loads up the `taxonomy-location.php` template.

Now, I'm adding the pagination feature to the theme. So I have this URL:

```
http://example.com/location/dc/page/2
```

and it won't load the `taxonomy-location.php` template, it actually loads the **404** template.

This is what the debug bar shows:

> [image: http://cl.ly/1u0F470k062o1Q121u15]

It seems like it's getting the right values, WP is just not loading up the correct template.

---

**EDIT** (Moved over from the comment links)

### `functions.php`

```
/* LOCATION */
add_rewrite_rule( 'location/([^/]+)/page/([0-9]{1,})/?$', 'index.php?location=$matches[1]&paged=$matches[2]', 'top' );
```

### `taxonomy-location.php`

```
  <?php 
  $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
  query_posts($query_string.'&posts_per_page=2&paged='.$paged);
  ?>

  <h2>"<?= ucwords(get_query_var('location')); ?>" Venues</h2>

  <?php if (have_posts()) : ?>

    <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

  <article>
    <h1><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h1>
    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail('venue_thumb'); ?></a>
  </article>

  <?php endwhile; ?>

    <?php wp_pagenavi(); ?>

  <?php else : ?>

    <article>
      <h1>No posts found</h1>
    </article>

<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Lots of things can mess this up. Do you have any plugins installed? Have you used "query_posts" in your development?

Comment: I do have a couple of plugins installed. I have, but only in the custom templates. It doesn't make sense that using query_posts would affect it since the template is not being loaded at all.

Comment: "query_posts", if used incorrectly, can have significant effects on the WordPress environment. In particular, it can change the main WP query which affects things like pagination. Can you do a pastebin of your template and your functions.php file?

Comment: @criticerz All your **additional info is spread around comments**. Please don't do that. Always update/edit your question and add the info to it. Then notify people in comments about your update.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `'paged' => get_query_var( 'page' )` to your query.

EDIT : For pagination to work properly the posts per page should be greater than 'Blog pages show at most' under Settings-> Reading section of the WordPress Admin. So there are two ways you can make this work out.

1. You can set 'Blog pages show at most' to 1. This would show 1 post in all the blog pages unless you specify post_per_pages specifically for each query.
2. The other option you have would be to use the `pre_get_posts` filter.

Example of pre_get_post filter to limit the no. of posts on a location taxonomy archive page to 2 posts per page.

```
function location_posts( $query ) {
    if( is_tax( 'location' ) ) {
        $query->set('posts_per_page', '2');
    }
    return $query;
}
add_filter('pre_get_posts', 'location_posts');
```

Comment: I am using that on my query already: http://cl.ly/3W2p220Z2t2w2e1e2L3A

Comment: You are using `get_query_var('paged')`. Try using `get_query_var('page')`. Notice 'page' instead of 'paged'.

Comment: Tried that and nothing. I'm pretty sure it's supposed to be "paged". Anyways, the issue I'm having doesn't even get to the query_posts. My problem is that once I add the "page/2" to the URL, it won't load the taxonomy-location.php template.

Comment: Can you tell me what 'Blog pages show at most' is set to under Settings-> Reading in the Dashboard?

Comment: Sure here you go: http://cl.ly/3h3T38413B0G2r0d0O2d

Comment: I have edited the answer. Let me know if it helps.

Answer (score 1):

I was running into the same issue.

Here is what I added to my functions.php to resolve the issue.

```
add_action(
    'pre_get_posts',
    function( $query ) {
        // When creating custom Rewrites we lose the paged number so we need to set it here.
        if ( preg_match( '/\/page\/([0-9]+)\/?/', ( ! empty( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ) ? sanitize_text_field( wp_unslash( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ) ) : '' ), $matches ) ) {
            if ( ! empty( $matches[1] ) && is_numeric( $matches[1] ) ) {
                set_query_var( 'paged', $matches[1] );
            }
        }
        return $query;
    }
);

add_action(
    'init',
    function() {
        add_rewrite_rule(
            'location/(.*)/page/([0-9]+)/?',
            'index.php?page=$matches[2]&taxonomy=location&location=$matches[1]',
            'top'
        );
    }
);
```

Notice that in the rewrite you must use `page=` and not `paged=`. Not sure why you can't use paged there.

Make sure you flush your rewrite rules afterward. (Re-save Permalinks)

Comment: Fantastic! I tried many other fixes for 404's with custom taxonomy pagination and this is the only thing that worked.

Answer (score 0):

```
register_post_type( 'lifestyle',
                array( 
                'label' => __('Lifestyle', 'tmi'), 
                'public' => true, 
                'show_ui' => true,
                'show_in_nav_menus' => true,
                'rewrite' => true,
                'hierarchical' => true,
                'menu_position' => 5,
                'exclude_from_search' =>false,
                'supports' => array(
                                     'title',
                                     'editor',
                                     'thumbnail',
                                     'excerpt',
                                     'revisions')
                    ) 
                );

    register_taxonomy('lifestylecat', __('lifestyle', 'tmi'),array('hierarchical' => true, 'label' =>  __('Categories', 'tmi'), 'singular_name' => __('Category', 'tmi'))
    );
```

Comment: Almost there. Please add an explanation to make this a legitimate answer.

Comment: **How** does this relate to the answer? Please edit your question or **delete** it.